# How to gain hard and soft threshold in discrete wavelet transform by integer samples

Tags: audio, image-processing, dwt

I gained samples of audio signal that have integer representation. I want to take dwt from samples and destroy them, by selected threshold. My problem is threshold choice.

Comment: What about a hard and soft thresholding by D. Donoho? The threshold can be estimated from the finest wavelet coefficients. Take a look at his papers: Ideal spatial adaptation via wavelet shrinkage, Nonlinear Wavelet Methods for Recovering Signals, Images, and Densities from indirect and noisy data, Wavelet Shrinkage: Asymptopia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must perform the following steps:

1. Calculate the forward DWT, with any reasonable wavelet (say, CDF 5/3 or CDF 9/7) and either with real numbers or integers.
2. Estimate the noise variance σ<sup>2</sup> from the finest wavelet coefficients *d*<sub>1</sub> using
   [image: sigma = med(|d1|)/0.6745].
   Note that this estimation is valid for an additive noise with the normal (Gaussian) distribution.
3. Determine the noise threshold as
   [image: lambda = sigma sqrt(2 ln N)],
   where the *N* is the length of the signal.
4. Perform the hard or soft thresholding using the estimated threshold.
5. Calculate the inverse DWT using the thresholded coefficients.

### References

- Donoho, D. L.; Johnstone, I. M.: Ideal Spatial Adaptation by Wavelet Shrinkage. *Biometrika*, vol. 81, no. 3, 1994, pp. 425–455.